# Given a string return the first character in the string if it contains more than 4 characters, and the last character otherwise

Tags: java, char

I have written a bit of code to try and solve my Given question, given a string return the first character in the string if it contains
more than 4 characters, and the last character otherwise. but I can't work it out, help with this would be greatly appreciated.

FOR EXAMPLE:
TEST - System.out.println(firstOrLastChar("njarx"));
AND THE RESULT SHOULD BE n

I tried some for loops and count values but I know this most probably isn't right

public String firstOrLastChar(String str) {

```
    int i,index=-1;
int *int[] count = new int[256];

for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
   count[*(str+i)]=0;
}

for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
   count[*(str+i)]++;
}

for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    if(count[*(str+i)]==1)
    {
        index=i;
        break;
    }
}

if(index==-1)
    return '@';
if else (return.last.char)

else
    return *(str+index);
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Java as it looks like you're trying to use c pointers. Also, can you clarify the problem a bit more please? "if it contains more than 4 characters" if the input string contains more than 4 characters?

Comment: Is there any relation to netbeans?

Comment: @Maia Good point - I removed the OP's netbeans tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like that :

```
if(myInput!=null){
    if(myInput.length()>4){
           System.out.println(myInput.charAt(0));
    }else{
           System.out.println(myInput.charAt(myInput.length()-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public char firstOrLastChar(String input) {
  if (input.length() > 4)
    return input.charAt(0);
  return input.charAt(input.length() - 1);
}
```

Optionally you could add a null check. For example:

```
public char firstOrLastChar(String input) {
  if (input == null)
    return '@'; // or whatever you want to do
  if (input.length() > 4)
    return input.charAt(0);
  return input.charAt(input.length() - 1);
}
```